# Parsing long literals from file input/variable Java

Tags: java, parsing, long-integer, literals, numberformatexception

I am trying to do some large computations from a list of numbers in a .txt file. I need to use longs, specifically literal longs and therefor I need to include 'L' or 'l' at the end each time I take a new value from the file. int litterals have been leaving me with negative answers...I have tried adding a 'L' suffix each time I read the file but Long.valueOf() throws a NumberFormatException. How can I declare a parsed long as a literal long?

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;
public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File numFile = new File("numbers.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(numFile);
    int total = 0;
    Long tmp;
    while(in.hasNextLine()){
        tmp = Long.valueOf(in.nextLine().substring(0,12));
        System.out.println(tmp);
        total += tmp;
    }
}
```

I appreciate all the help on here but you are all kind of ignoring my question... MY QUESTION IS: How can I declare a parsed long as a literal long?(Considering I never hard wire a value). The example above is unrelated, it doesnt need debugging, it is just a brief demo of what I am trying to do.

Comment: You don't need to add any L anywhere. That is useful only when you want a literal long value *in the code*. using `Long.valueOf("1234")` will get you a `Long`.

Comment: Can you print the value of `in.nextLine().substring(0,12)` that's failing?

Comment: What is an example of a complete line?

Comment: There is no such type as a "literal long". A long is a long is a long.

Answer (score 2):

If the individual numbers are too large for `int`, their sum will be as well. Use also a `long` for the total.